# Using Direct2D across DLL boundaries

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll, direct2d

So I started writing a program in C that would require a lot of fancy drawing, but I'm strictly on Windows, so I decided to use Direct2D.

As of right now I create a custom control in a DLL, which the program consumes and uses like any other Win32 control. The custom control sets up a D2D context inside its window and draws into it for whatever it needs, and this works fine.

I realized this would make for a very useful DLL in future projects for setting up and tearing down Direct2D easily through a traditional control interface, so I made the control send a notification to the parent window when it was time to draw instead of calling its own internal drawing code (basically like owner-drawn controls). It calls BeginDraw, then sends the notification to the parent with a custom NMHDR that includes a pointer to the ID2D1DCRenderTarget, then calls EndDraw. In my main window, I create the control, then respond to the notification, then call methods to draw stuff, then return.

The problem is that when EndDraw is called in the DLL, I get the error "The object was not in the correct state to process the method". This makes me think that crossing DLL boundaries must muck with the operation. Do DLLs always run in the same thread as the attached process? Is there some other oddity about crossing through DLL boundaries, especially with respect to Direct2D?

Thanks.

Comment: You should really use a debugger. You will immediately see if your threading suspicions are correct.

Comment: So I have been beating my head on it for a while using Visual Studio 2012 and its debugger, but I'm not very well-versed at debugging stuff like this. I'd appreciate some pointers on how to use the debugger to shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Calling into a DLL is just like calling any other function.  I'd look to see if you're getting message interleaving issues (i.e., if you're getting an extra start message before your end message).

Comment: COM also has a restriction on making COM calls while processing a message sent as a result of another COM call, which may or may not be the cause here but always manages to trip me up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses! Just realized that it had to do with the binding of the DC to the RenderTarget, so blame me.

Answer (score 0):

> This makes me think that crossing DLL boundaries must muck with the operation. Do DLLs always run in the same thread as the attached process? Is there some other oddity about crossing through DLL boundaries, especially with respect to Direct2D?

No, calling a function that lives in a different DLL is no different from calling a function in the same module as the caller. Remember that the standard Windows controls always exist in different modules from their hosts, e.g. user32.dll, comctl32.dll and so on.

The problem in your code is not related to it residing in a different module.